# About initializing a vector in C++ with { }

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, initialization, list-initialization

In Stroustrup's book, "Programming: Principles and Practices of Programming Using C++ (Second Edition)", the author creates three vectors as followed in their own struct:

```
struct Day {
    vector<double> hour{ vector<double>(24,not_a_reading) };
};

struct Month { // a month of temperature readings
    int month{ not_a_month }; // [0:11] January is 0
    vector<Day> day{ 32 }; // [1:31] one vector of readings per day
};

struct Year { // a year of temperature readings, organized by month
    int year; // positive == A.D.
    vector<Month> month{ 12 }; // [0:11] January is 0
};
```

My question is, why does `vector<Day> day{32};` create a vector of type Day with a size of 32, whereas `vector<int>{32};` creates a vector of size 1?

Comment: `Day` doesn't have such constructor (`Day::Day(int)`), so it creates 32 default items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `type name{...};` syntax (known as *uniform initialization*) was added in C++11, and was supposed to become *the* new initialization syntax, superseding other alternatives. It has some advantages over the alternatives, so some people actively promote it.

But there's a problem with it: it behaves weirdly with some classes that weren't written with it in mind (mostly standard containers, that were designed before it was a thing).

What happens is, `vector<T> name{...}` first attempts to use constructors with a `std::initializer_list` parameter (which succeeds for `vector<int> name{42};`, initializing the vector with a single number `42`), and if it fails, it attempts to use other contructors (`vector<Day> int{42};` ends up using the constructor with a single `size_t size` parameter, filling the vector with 42 default-constructed objects).

If you think that this behavior is peculiar, you're not alone.

The rule of thumb is:

- Avoid the `type name{...}` syntax when dealing with containers (or completely).
- If you want to initialize a container with a list, use `vector<T> name = {...};`.
  (`vector<Day> name = {42};` will not compile.)
- If you want to use some other contructor of a container, use `vector<T> name(...);`.
  (`vector<int> name(42);` will fill the vector with 42 zeroes.)

Note that `vector<T> name(...);` will not work *at class scope*. You can use `vector<T> name = vector<T>(...);` instead.

Comment: Thanks alot, really informative, however could you clarify on why ```vector<T> name(...);``` doesn't work in a class scope?

Comment: @Horashio Not sure. Probably because it looks too similar to a method declaration, so it would be hard for a compiler to distinguish it from one.

Answer (score 1):

When the initializer is an initializer list when at first the constructor that accepts std::initializer_list is considered.

So for this declaration

```
std::vector<int> v{32};
```

there is used the constrictor of the class std::vector that has the first parameter of the type `std::initializer_list<T`>.

```
vector(initializer_list<T>, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

In this case the `std::initializer_list<int>` contains only one element equal to 32.

In this declaration

```
std::vector<Day> day{32};
```

the initializer list { 32 } can not be converted to `std::initializer_list<Day>`. So the constructor that accepts an initializer list is not suitable.

In this case the compiler considers another constructors and finds the constructor that accepts an integer as the number of elements in the vector.

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

Pay attention to that this constructor is explicit. So for example you can not write

```
std::vector<Day> day = {32};
```

From the C++ 17 Standard (13.3.1.7 Initialization by list-initialization)

> 1 When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized such
>   that 8.5.4 specifies that overload resolution is performed according
>   to the rules in this section, **overload resolution selects the
>   constructor in two phases**:
>
> (1.1) — **Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list
>   constructors (8.5.4) of the class T** and the argument list consists
>   of the initializer list as a single argument.
>
> (1.2) — **If no viable initializer-list constructor is found**,
>   overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions
>   are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists
>   of the elements of the initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` [has](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) fill and initializer list constructors that suits us.

`Day` can't be value-initialized to `32`, so fill constructor is called.

This can be easily verified by adding appropriate Day's constructor:

```cpp
struct Day {
    Day(int) {}
    vector<double> hour{ vector<double>(24,not_a_reading) };
};

struct Month { // a month of temperature readings
    int month{ not_a_month }; // [0:11] January is 0
    vector<Day> day{ 32 }; // [1:31] one vector of readings per day
};

struct Year { // a year of temperature readings, organized by month
    int year; // positive == A.D.
    vector<Month> month{ 12 }; // [0:11] January is 0
};

// vector<Day> day{32};
// day.size() == 1
```